# Find all phrases enclosed with (" ") and words without (" ") in an expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Language being used: PHP

Lets say I have an expression like this:

`Ayala NOT ("Ayala Station" OR "Ayala Branch" OR "Joey Ayala")`

And I want to extract the following words: 
- **Ayala** 
- **Ayala Station** 
- **Ayala Branch** and 
- **Joey Ayala**

I want to retrieve all phrases enclosed in double quotation mark **" "** and stand-alone words like the *Ayala* in the example above, but failed with experiments

**Tried multiple regex**

**1st attempt:**

`"([^"]+)"` - I'm aware that this regex is the correct one for getting words/phrases inside double quotation mark

**2nd attempt:**

`~\w+(?:-\w+)*~` - this regex will get all words from a given expression or string

**3rd attempt:**

Combining the 2 attempts above
`"([^"]+)"|~\w+(?:-\w+)*~` - I was able to produce my use cases for my desired output but with these 2 combined, the **Ayala** word isn't being extracted

Example playground [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nP6wM5/6)

**4th attempt:**

Tried using `"([^"]+)"|\S+` but it is including the special characters

[image: 4th Attempt]

Am I missing something with the regex?

Comment: NOT and OR are both standalone words too, why don't they get matched too? Are they just special exceptions?

Comment: they're also being matched too sir, I just use this code to omit them `$arrkeywords = array_map('strtolower', $arrkeywords);
        $arrkeywords = array_diff($arrkeywords, array("or", "and"));`

Comment: Remove the `~` delimiters - delimiters should only occur at the very start and very end of the pattern https://regex101.com/r/nP6wM5/8

Comment: excellent Captain! may you kindly give an answer below so I can upvote and mark your comment as the answer? :)

Comment: [Another idea at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XupiH4/1) by use of [branch reset](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) for getting matches in **group 1** and [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to skip the unwanted. Delimiter issue has been pointed out already. Further I don't think it's a good idea to work with lookarounds and balanced quotes (eg [see this](https://regex101.com/r/nP6wM5/14)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side of the alternation should not have regex delimiters - the regex delimiters should only be around the *entire pattern* (next to the PHP string delimiters). Eg

[`"([^"]+)"|\w+(?:-\w+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/nP6wM5/8)

If you want to capture all matches at once, without capture groups, you can use

```
(?<=")\b[^"]+(?=")|\w+(?:-\w+)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/nP6wM5/10

To exclude NOT and OR in the regex itself, use:

```
(?<=")\b[^"]+(?=")|\b(?!(?:NOT|OR)(?!-))\w+(?:-\w+)*
```

to negative lookahead for them right before matching the standalone words.

Comment: thank you very much Captain! very helpful, appreciate it!